# Masonry not working in IE 7. SCRIPT5009: 'Element' is undefined masonry.pkgd.min.js, line 9 character 6316

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a strange issue with the latest version of masonry. Got it to work before but for a new project I downloaded the latest versions of both jQuery and Masonry, and all works fine. Except IE7 won't load the Masonry library due to an error in the plugin so it seems.

I got this error in the IE7 console:

[image]

This is the entire code of my test-file, so anybody can quickly reproduce it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='masonry.pkgd.min.js?ver=3.0.0'></script>
</head>
<body>
Test
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something obvious or is Masonry no longer compatible with IE7? I didn't find anything about this on the website.

As you can see I'm using jQuery 1.10.1 and Masonry 3.0.0

Edit: I tried with the non-minimized version, and I get

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Element' is undefined
masonry.pkgd.js, line 914 character 1
```

Strange, because there is nothing called `Element` on that line..

here's a snippet of masonry.pkgd.js:

```
911    /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true, unused: true */
912    /*global define: false */
913    
914    ( function( global, ElemProto ) {
915    
916      'use strict';
917    
918      var matchesMethod = ( function() {
919        // check un-prefixed
920        if ( ElemProto.matchesSelector ) {
921          return 'matchesSelector';
922        }
```

Comment: The "Element" you see in the error message it's there because the function is getting `Element.prototype` as a second parameter (asigned to `ElemProto`)

Comment: I am getting the same error in ie8.0.7601.17514
Line: 9 Char: 1 though

Comment: I do get this error in IE8 as well, also line 9 char 1. masonry did not produce any errors in older browsers before, there the wrong answer was given here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read about the library support on their FAQ page](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html)

> **What is Masonry’s browser support?**
>
> Masonry works in ***IE8+*** and modern browsers, including mobile browsers
>   on iOS and Android.

Comment: Oh, really? Ok, thanks. I think it's kind of strange because it worked on another site of mine: http://bdwm.be/cs/ (works great in IE7).

So do you think I should revert to the older version of Masonry then?

Also, I think it kind of sucks because including Masonry in my website causes all my other javascript to fail too.. I don't think this should be happening

Comment: Do you really have an IE7 user base? [It is <1% globally.](http://theie7countdown.com/)

Comment: I know it's not much. I don't support ie6 anymore. But you would be amazed how many "older" people are still on IE7. And the website I'm making is for a historical museum, so yeah.. I'm afraid IE7 support is needed.. Also keep in mind that 1% is still 70 million people

Comment: @JulesColle In this case, you should make your website work on IE7, but without the full functionality that modern browsers support. Masonry is just making the layout prettier, but if not working it should not prevent visitors to use the site. Follow [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) guideline.

Comment: @epascarello Some of us are stuck with not only IE7, but IE6 due to certain clients who won't give it up for various reasons...

Comment: Whoever downvoted, guess what, you can not magically make IE7 support something when it is not written for IE7. There is no solution other than to not rely on this framework if you need IE7 support.

Comment: This answer is wrong! Just as Kiers commented above I do have this error in IE8 as well with a new project and before masonry dit not produce errors if you were in an older browser. But since I am using the same masonry version like in the earlier project, but a newer jQuery version the problem seems to lie there.

Answer (score 0):

In case this can still be useful to anyone, Masonry really doesn't support IE7 - there is also a won't-fix issue about this on github - https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/356.
Still I wanted to prevent the javascript from breaking entirely for IE7 users, so I've added the following (which helps if you are using masonry as a jQuery plugin):

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.")!=-1{
      $.fn.masonry = function() { };
}else{
      <!-- ORIGINAL MASONRY CODE GOES HERE -->
      ...
      ...
}
```

This will create an empty jQuery plugin called Masonry in case of IE7 and will prevent the script from breaking the entire javascript of the page (of course the Masonry stub does nothing in that scenario but at least we prevented the error and other stuff can still work)